# GitHub-Action black formatter

Tags: github, github-actions

A github action is written to test the black formatter on the following code:

```py
# Let's test the black formatter with
""" def my_function(x,y): 
  if x> y:return y
  else:
     return x """

def my_function(x,y): 
  if x> y:return y
  else:
     return x

# It should become
""" def my_function(x, y):
    if x > y:
        return y
    else:
        return x """
```

The github-action is written as follows

```yaml
name: black-formatting-check

on: [push, pull_request]

permissions:
  contents: write
  pull-requests: write

jobs:
  linter_name:
    name: runner / black
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Black formatting
      uses: datadog/action-py-black-formatter@v2.1
      id: action_black

    - name: Suggest code formatting changes
      uses: reviewdog/action-suggester@v1
      with:
        tool_name: blackfmt

    # Set up Git so that the commit is made by the GitHub Actions user.
    - name: Set up Git and commit changes
      run: |
        git config --local user.email "${{ github.actor }}@users.noreply.github.com"
        git config --local user.name "${{ github.repository }} Actions"
        git add -A
        if git diff --cached --exit-code; then
          echo "No changes to commit"
        else
          git commit -m "Automated commit by GitHub Action"
          git push
        fi
```

the problem is that the corrected code never gets pushed back to the repo, no matter what I try. What's wrong with my github action?

Thank you in advance